# Subdirectories and the Rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I have this directory structure in my project:

```
- assets
-- images
--- game
--- avatars
```

I reference an image in avatars in code like this:

```
image_tag('avatar.png')
```

In development this works, in production I'm getting an error.

I have this code in application.rb

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

When I compile my assets in development I see they are being created in public, under their subdirectories.  So like this:

```
- public
-- assets
--- game
--- avatars
```

But in the log I'm seeing this:

```
http://demo1e97.lvh.me:3000/assets/avatar-edc80241a6bae07d6ed70cdffef15753.png
```

So it isn't using the subdirectory there.

What is the best way to solve this so it works both in development and in production?  Should all the images be written into one directory in public, or should I include the subfolder when referencing the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always include the relative path (under `assets/images`) when referencing the image, like this:

```
<%= image_tag("avatars/avatar.png") %>
```

That will resolve to the file located at `app/assets/images/avatars/avatar.png` and will  ensure it works in all environments. You can then completely remove this code from `application.rb`:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Point number: 1
As long as you are adding subdirectories to images, stylesheets, javascripts you won't need to add them to assets path. All the subdirectories becomes /assets.

So your current help will generate here:

```
<%= image_tag("game/avatar.png") %> 
=> http://demo1e97.lvh.me:3000/assets/avatar.png
```

And this is the convention so you don't need to put them in your public folder. While you are deploying to production, your asset precompilation process will take that to public folder by maintaining the asset menifest.